# How to check if all spring placeholders exist?

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration, placeholder

I have java spring application, that uses in xml files placeholders values of them taken from app.properties. Is it possible to create test or something similar without starting application and getting up spring context that names all placeholders used in xml files (where beans are configured) are correct, nothing missing, nothing misspelled etc. ?
Thanks.

Comment: what would you like to do if they are misspelled or missing?

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to get a reference to the ApplicationContext and actually create every bean.  This should throw an exception if something was not defined correctly.

```
String[] beanNames = getAppContext().getBeanDefinitionNames();

for (int i = 0; i < beanNames.length; i++)
{
   BeanDefinition beanDefinition = getAppContext().getBeanFactory()
               .getBeanDefinition(beanNames[i]);

   if (!beanDefinition.isAbstract())
   {
      getAppContext().getBean(beanNames[i]);
   }
}
```